# SQLCommand update query in batches

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I have written a code like following:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < ListToUpdate.Count; i = i + 500)
 {
   SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
   command.Connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=mydb;Integrated Security=SSPI");
   command.Connection.Open();
   var batchList = ListToUpdate.Skip(i).Take(500);
   for (int j = 0; j < batchList.Count(); j++)
   {
      command.CommandText += string.Format("update mytable set column=@s_id{0} where columnid = @id{0};", j);
      command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@s_id" + j, ListToUpdate[j].QuantitySoldTotal);
      command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id" + j, ListToUpdate[j].ItemId);
   }
   command.ExecuteNonQuery();
   command.Connection.Close();
 }
```

This should perform update of my table in batches, but the weird thing is the query gets executed only the first time...

If there are 1500 items in list, only the first batch get updated... And the others aren't ...

What am I doing wrong here ???

Comment: I think you need to use batchList [j] instate of  ListToUpdate[j]

Comment: @PravinTukadiya omg thats it hahaha.. How could I've forgotten to change it! Im testing now, thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have to close and reopen connection every time you iterate? Once, you have the connection open, just create a new sql command text after each batch update using

```
command.CommandText = CommandType.Text;
```

I'd suggest this -

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
command.Connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=mydb;Integrated Security=SSPI");
command.Connection.Open();

for (int i = 0; i < ListToUpdate.Count; i = i + 500) {
    var batchList = ListToUpdate.Skip(i).Take(500);
    for (int j = 0; j < batchList.Count(); j++) {
        command.CommandText += string.Format("update mytable set column=@s_id{0} where columnid = @id{0};", j);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@s_id" + j, batchList[j].QuantitySoldTotal);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id" + j, batchList[j].ItemId)
    }
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    command.CommandText = CommandType.Text;
}
command.Connection.Close();
```

Select properties from the new list generated such as `batchList[j]`.

Comment: Okay one sec ill test this method

Comment: Sajal, why do you put ExecuteNonQuery() inside the for loop ? isn't the purpose of batch to execute 500 updates all at once, instead of doing it each time the inside loop iterates? Thus if collection has 2000 items it is 2000 times slower?

Comment: yeah, correct. See the update to my answer. Once, a batch is executed, issue a new command text for the next batch of updates.

Comment: still doesn't works unfortuntately... Says that the variable with name s_id0 has already been declared? o.o

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use batchList.

```
for (int i = 0; i < ListToUpdate.Count; i = i + 500)
{
  SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
  command.Connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial 
  Catalog=mydb;Integrated Security=SSPI");
  command.Connection.Open();
  var batchList = ListToUpdate.Skip(i).Take(500);
  for (int j = 0; j < batchList.Count(); j++)
  {
       command.CommandText += string.Format("update mytable set 
       column=@s_id{0} where columnid = @id{0};", j);
       command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@s_id" + j, 
       batchList[j].QuantitySoldTotal);
       command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id" + j, batchList[j].ItemId);
       command.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }

  command.Connection.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the placement of `command.ExecuteNonQuery();` is not correct

please check the below code , if it helps

```
for (int i = 0; i < ListToUpdate.Count; i = i + 500)
 {
   SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
   command.Connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=mydb;Integrated Security=SSPI");
   command.Connection.Open();
   var batchList = ListToUpdate.Skip(i).Take(500);
   for (int j = 0; j < batchList.Count(); j++)
   {
   command.CommandText += string.Format("update mytable set column=@s_id{0} where columnid = @id{0};", j);
   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@s_id" + j, ListToUpdate[j].QuantitySoldTotal);
   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id" + j, ListToUpdate[j].ItemId);


   command.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
   command.Connection.Close();
 }
```

Comment: But this would execute each query each time... 2000 items = 2000 querie... ?